# How can I initialize an Alamofire Manager with a DVR Session?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, nsurlsession

I want to initialize an `Alamofire Manager` with a `DVR Session` in order to record and play back network requests for testing. When the [`Manager`'s initializer](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/Manager.swift#L149) accesses the `Session`'s delegate it throws an `unrecognized selector` exception. If anyone uses `Alamofire` and `DVR` together, can you please share your initialization code?

Here's what I have:

```
let api: OurAPI

let maybeSession = dvrCassetteName.flatMap{ cassetteName -> Session? in
    let delegate = Manager.SessionDelegate()
    let backingSession = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration(), delegate: delegate, delegateQueue: nil)
    let maybeBundle = NSBundle.allBundles().filter{ $0.bundlePath.lowercaseString.containsString("xctest") }.first
    if let bundle = maybeBundle {
        let session = Session(outputDirectory: "~/Desktop/DVR/", cassetteName: cassetteName, testBundle: bundle, backingSession: backingSession)
        return session
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}

if let session = maybeSession, manager = Alamofire.Manager(session: session, delegate: Manager.SessionDelegate()) {
    api = OurAPI(manager: manager)
} else {
    api = OurAPI()
}
```

[Here's the PR](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/pull/795) on Alamofire that introduces the initializer I'm using, in whose discussion they discuss my use case, but there's no mention of the `unrecognized selector`. I've also tried forking `DVR` and overriding `delegate` to point to `backingSession.delegate` but still getting the exception.

Answer (score 0):

The failable init from Alamofire.Manager is the culprit at this line: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/Manager.swift#L171

The problem is that we can't set the delegate directly on the session since it's a get-only property.

Here's what I had to do to work around this:

```
class RecordSession: Session {
    override var delegate: NSURLSessionDelegate? {
        get {
            return backingSession.delegate
        }
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure I am not of the woods yet but this at least gets us over this issue.